# Use cordova plugins inside Ionic Vue.js Components

Tags: vue.js, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I see I can use any cordova plugin within ionic capacitor. But how I can use it inside vue component for example.

Just for example:

1. I installed plugin `cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice` with npm

`npm i --save cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice`

2. I trying to `import foo from "cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice"`, but it says cannot find that module.

Is there a special way to import plugins like the above example plugin (or any other plugin which is not in `@ionic-native` namespace)?

##### I need usage example for the ionic vue community bacause it's very hard to found any info how we can use it.

**This not working for `cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice`**

```
import PLUGIN_X from "PLUGIN_X"

export default defineComponent({
  // ...
  mounted() {
    PLUGIN_X.doSomething()
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import the plugin, the plugin is available on window object.

You can do something [like this](https://github.com/flotrugliocoffice/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice#usage-in-typescript):

```
  // Enable
  (<any>window).plugins.preventscreenshot.enable((a) => this.successCallback(a), (b) => this.errorCallback(b));

  // Disable
  (<any>window).plugins.preventscreenshot.disable((a) => this.successCallback(a), (b) => this.errorCallback(b));

  successCallback(result) {
    console.log(result); // true - enabled, false - disabled
  }

  errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

or [like this](https://github.com/flotrugliocoffice/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice#usage-in-javascript) if using javascript instead of typescript

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// Enable
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.plugins.preventscreenshot.enable(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
// Disable
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.plugins.preventscreenshot.disable(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function successCallback(result) {
  console.log(result); // true - enabled, false - disabled
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log(error);
}


document.addEventListener("onTookScreenshot",function(){
// Receive notification when screenshot is ready;
});

document.addEventListener("onGoingBackground",function(){
// Receive notification when control center or app going in background.
});
```